# What's the definition of $C_0(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

Here is a definition of $C_0(\Omega)$ in wikipedia: (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanish_at_infinity)

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a locally compact space.
>
> Let's call "a function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ vanishes at infinity" iff $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists$ a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $\forall x\in X\setminus K, |f(x)|<\epsilon$.
>
> Then $C_0(X,\mathbb{F})$ is defined as the set of functions $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ vanish at infinity.

As it says, this definition does not require functions to be continuous, and it's really weird since one usually denotes set of functions as '$C$' when it is a subset of the set of continuous functions..

Also, I have seen some papers require $C_0$ to be continuous.

What is the usual definition of $C_0(X)$?

Comment: Let $X' = X \cup \{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $X$. The condition is equivalent to saying that if $f$ is extended to $X'$ by writing $f(\infty) = 0$, then $f$ is continuous at $\infty$.

Comment: @Dave Yes, I know that, but in general does $C_0$ mean the set of functions continuous at $\infty$? Or continuous on $X\cup \{\infty\}$?

Comment: I don't know. I was just suggesting one possible reason for the notation with $C$ even if continuity wasn't assumed.

Comment: I've only seen $C_0(X)$ as containing continuous functions. The wikipedia page is actually kinda strange (talking about norms in locally compact spaces, using norm notation instead of absolute value...).

Comment: Odd. Usually I've seen $C_0(X)$ some space of functions that are continuous and either compactly supported, decay quickly at infinity, etc. The continuity assumption was always built in, though.